# PostMessage in C# is not sending the key

Tags: c#, bots, postmessage

I'm trying to simulate a keystroke ("z") on another window, a game in particular.
I've implemented in my program a simple timer that sends the key with PostMessage every 1000ms, but the "action" related to the pressing of that key doesn't start.
I've analysed the Messages sent to the window of the game with Spy++, but the strange thing is that i can see the exact sequence of messages (KEYDOWN, CHAR and KEYUP), whether i press it manually or send it through my application. Obviously if i press "z" manually the game's function gets called correctly.
Here i report the messages that i get from Spy++, the first 3 are from me hitting z manually, the last 3 are from my software.
[Messages from Spy++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAs1R.png)

And here i include the code that i'm using

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, uint lParam);

private void SendKeys(IntPtr proc_hwnd, IntPtr key)
        {
            PostMessage(proc_hwnd, 0x100, key, 0x002C0001);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            PostMessage(proc_hwnd, 0x101, key, 0xC02C0001);
        }
 Process[] proc;

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("Proc_name");
            if (proc.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No process found");
                return;
            } 

            tmr_raccogli.Interval = (int)(num_raccogli.Value * 1000);
            tmr_raccogli.Start();
        }

       
        private void tmr_raccogli_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendKeys(proc[0].MainWindowHandle, (IntPtr)Keys.Z);
        }
```

I don't get why it's not working since from that point of view the two actions are identical.

Comment: Both wParam and lParam should be IntPtr.  Did you try it that way, yet?

Comment: Yes i've tried with lParam being IntPtr, but it gives me an error on the second PostMessage on (IntPtr)0xC02C0001, "Overflow of an arithmetic operation"

Comment: So.  Here's a question, are you using the Unicode version PostMessageW (because all of .NET is written for Unicode, it makes sense to use only the Unicode versions of the various p/Invokes) and the second question is... are you building it native to x64?  Because I know that apps compiled for AnyCPU or 32 bit don't always answer the phone when invoking native functions unless you build native for x64 since 32 bit apps are sandboxed.  There are actually 2 different window threads running on 64 bit systems because of this.

Comment: *two different window management systems, not threads.  I typed too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

i don't have an exact answer but i might able to guide you in the right direction.

The focus and foreground state of your window maybe important as well as the input thread.
SetFocus
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setfocus
SetForegroundWindow
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow
AttachThreadInput
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-attachthreadinput

Your windows receives the messages but i decides to ignore them, this depends on how the implementation of windows msgs is programmed in the target. I can remember creating something similar and AttachThreadInput fixed most of my code interoperability problems.